# I'm new to Mac development in Flutter and I'm getting error on build

Tags: ios, flutter, info.plist

I'm new to developing for Mac devices and I'm having a problem compiling the project, getting a "Found non-key" error. Where am I going wrong?

> Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
> /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error: Found non-key inside  at line 7 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0.
> Building com.example.silvestreapp for device (ios)...

Below is my Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">   
    <dict>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
```

Someone to help me?

Comment: Yup, well, you've certainly hosed the Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

You've screwed up your *Info.plist*. Change

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
```

To

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

And try not to edit the *Info.plist* manually, as it is very easy to make a mistake. Use the editor interface.